# Getting Forbidden Error using Superagent

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, superagent

Below is my index.js file

I am trying to get back a response from a sports data api. I can fire curl requests at it without trouble, but when I try and do it this way, I receive a forbidden 403 error.

```
var express = require('express');
var config = require("../config.js");
var superagent = require("superagent");
var router = express.Router();
var timer = require('timers');
var isInitialized = false;
var isUpdating = false;
var timerId;
var admin;
var db;
var games = {};
var ref; //games ref to realtime database
/* GET home page. */
router.get('/index', function(req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.query);
  startUpdate();

  res.render('index', { title: 'CBB update' , isUpdating: isUpdating});
});

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.query);
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' , isUpdating: isUpdating});
});

};

  for(var id in games){
     var fantasyUrl = 'https://api.sportradar.us/ncaamb-t3/games/' + games[id].gameID + '/boxscore.json?api_key='+ config.fantasy.primaryKey;

  const uid = id;
    var request = superagent.get(fantasyUrl)
     .set('X-Originating-Ip', '73.60.233.133')
      .end(function(err, res){
        if(err){
              console.log(err);
             return;
           }


    };
```

Below is my terminal output

```
{ Error: Forbidden
    at Request.callback (/Users/nishonradhakrishnan/Desktop/bettorhalf-sportradar/node_modules/superagent/lib/node/index.js:674:11)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/Users/nishonradhakrishnan/Desktop/bettorhalf-sportradar/node_modules/superagent/lib/node/index.js:881:18)
    at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:974:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
  status: 403,
  response: 
   Response {
     domain: null,
     _events: {},
     _eventsCount: 0,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     res: 
      IncomingMessage {
        _readableState: [Object],
        readable: false,
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 4,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        socket: [Object],
        connection: [Object],
        httpVersionMajor: 1,
        httpVersionMinor: 1,
        httpVersion: '1.1',
        complete: true,
        headers: [Object],
        rawHeaders: [Object],
        trailers: {},
        rawTrailers: [],
        upgrade: false,
        url: '',
        method: null,
        statusCode: 403,
        statusMessage: 'Forbidden',
        client: [Object],
        _consuming: true,
        _dumped: false,
        req: [Object],
        text: '<h1>Developer Over Qps</h1>',
        read: [Function] },
```

Answer (score 0):

The `fantasyUrl` variable is wrong you don't need to start with `https://api.sportradar.us`